# Replace timestamp format in a file

Tags: linux, shell, date, timestamps

I have a file which contains the timestamp format like below.

```
'2020-03-07T14:42:36Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=16913 userid=1 xid=5326 ]' LOG: SET statement_timeout TO 120000
```

I want to change this timestamp format to

```
2020-03-07 14:42:36 UTC
```

in this file.

It's a log file where I don't have access to change the format directly, and it has billions of lines like this.

Comment: "billions" of lines? Do you need to rewrite the log file, or just transform the date while you're processing the log for some purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/T/ /' -e 's/Z//' file
```

or, equivalently,

```
sed 's/T/ /; s/Z//' file
```

This first replace the first `T` character on each line of the file with a space, and then remove the first occurrence of a `Z`.  This would convert

```
'2020-03-07T14:42:36Z UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=16913 userid=1 xid=5326 ]' LOG: SET statement_timeout TO 120000
```

into

```
'2020-03-07 14:42:36 UTC [ db=dev user=rdsdb pid=16913 userid=1 xid=5326 ]' LOG: SET statement_timeout TO 120000
```

Redirect to a new file to save the data.  If you want to do an in-place edit on the file, first make sure that the edits seems to be carried out correctly (the command assumes that there will be no more and no less than exactly one such timestamp on each line), then you may possibly use `sed -i` to change the file in place.

Comment: But this will replace if I have T or Z in my logs right?

Comment: @Bhuvanesh Yes, and you have, in the timestamp.  The `sed` command will only replace the _first_ occurrences on each line.  If you have lines with no timestamp, then you may instead change other data on the lines erroneously (you say nothing about this in the question).

Comment: Oh then it's great, all of my lines starts with timestamp